# In math, what is a chessboard + pieces?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

What mathematical concept would a chessboard + pieces be? Is there any matrix where the squares are kinda related, in the same way that for example a rock relates to all the column/row, where it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring other pieces, each of the chess pieces have a fixed set of legal moves from a given square (with some exceptions: pawns can capture [en passant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant) and [promote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promotion_%28chess%29), and there is also [castling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castling)).  These can be represented as graphs (in the sense of [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory)).

For example, the following image ("borrowed" from Wikipedia) represents the legal moves by a knight:

[image: Knight's graph]

A knight's tour of the chessboard is equivalent to a [Hamilton path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) of the above graph.

This could be represented as a $(0,1)$-matrix by taking its [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).